# hidding div's when a reload webpage

Tags: jquery, html

I want div's to be hidden at the beginning (m_royal and m_suite). Then when i do click, just shows the one that must be visible and hide the rest of div.
Problem is that it just works when i reload my page.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".contExp .post div").hide();

  $('.contExp .post a').click(function(){
      $(".contExp .post div").hide();
      var id =  $(this).attr('id');
      id = id.split('_');                               
      $(".contExp .post #m_"+id).show();              
   });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.contExp .post{font-size: 12px; margin-left: 5px; color:#505050;}
.contExp .post a{cursor:pointer;}
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="contExp">                  
       <div class='post'>                           
          <a id='royal'>+/- Detail</a>
          <div  id='m_royal'>                       
        -- Content to show 1
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class='post'>                           
          <a id='suite'>+/- Detail</a>
          <div  id='m_suite'>                                       
        -- Content to show 2
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".contExp .post div").hide();

  $('.contExp .post a').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('div').toggle();            
   });
});
```

or check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9D2J/1/

As soon as you click on the `<a>` element, it will search inside it's parent for a div and toggle that. toggle() allows you to show or hide an element, depending on the current state of the element, so if it's hidden, it will show it, if it's already visible, it will hide it.